# Timer doesn't start in viewWillAppear Methods

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to start a timer when a `viewWillAppear` method gets called.

It's working perfectly, but I'm having a problem when I push a new view on this Current View, which already has a timer. When I pop that new View and recall `viewWillAppear` I want to start the timer again as before. I have most of the techniques but can't find a solution.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];
       [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(createTimer) toTarget:self withObject:self];
 }


 - (void)createTimer 
{       
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

  gameTimer = [[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.00 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:gameTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
  timeCount = 360; 
  [runLoop run];
  [pool release];

}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer 
{
   if(timeCount == 0)
   {
      [self timerExpired];
   } else {
      timeCount--;
       if(timeCount == 0) {
           [timer invalidate];
           [self timerExpired];
       }
    }
    timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",timeCount/60, timeCount % 60];
}


- (void) timerExpired 
{
    //NSLog(@"Final == %@",arrayAnswers);
    //NSLog(@"Attempt == %d",[arrayAnswers count]);

    [gameTimer invalidate];
    gameTimer = nil;
}
```

Comment: It's very helpful if you [show **the relevant** portion of your code](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so that people are able to identify where your problem is.

Comment: have you tried `[timer invalidate];` ??

Comment: I have tried all possible way that I can do but still not get solution

Comment: Now I have add code that I am usning

Comment: Where is your viewWillDisappear code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on experience, your problem is the timer's thread. Basically, the problem is here:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(createTimer) toTarget:self withObject:self];
```

I'm not absolutely sure but I believe that your code is not really wrong. I haven't figured it out yet but I guess the NSTimer object is not being activated when `detachNewThreadSelector:` is used. Try executing the timer on the main thread.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(createTimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]
```

I've done this and got the results that I wanted.